# Linear regression with one feature from Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, scikit-learn

I have tried the code below

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np

# Assign the dataframe to this variable.
# TODO: Load the data
bmi_life_data = pd.read_csv("bmi_and_life_expectancy.csv")
X= bmi_life_data['BMI'].values.reshape(-1,1)
y = bmi_life_data['Life expectancy'].values.reshape(-1,1)

# Make and fit the linear regression model
#TODO: Fit the model and Assign it to bmi_life_model
bmi_life_model = LinearRegression()
bmi_life_model.fit(X,y) 

# Mak a prediction using the model
# TODO: Predict life expectancy for a BMI value of 21.07931
laos_life_exp = bmi_life_model.predict(21.07931)
```

but it gives me the error

> Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Even after reshaping it. I have tried to not reshape it but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Provide a small sample of your dataframe to have a look. For training and testing.

Comment: `
Country,Life expectancy,BMI
Afghanistan,52.8,20.62058
Albania,76.8,26.44657
Algeria,75.5,24.59620
`

Comment: I mean, at least 5 rows to have a look at the shape.

Comment: Provide the data in the question. Not in the comments

Comment: The error is due to prediction and not because of the fitting. ie do `bmi_life_model.predict(np.array([[21.07931]]))`

Comment: Thanks everyone the error was due to the prediction line.

Comment: This is (in part) why you should always provide the full error traceback: it shows exactly where the error originates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in the prediction line

`laos_life_exp = bmi_life_model.predict(21.07931)`

should be

`laos_life_exp = bmi_life_model.predict([[21.07931]])`

to be of appropriate dimension

Thanks to @onyambu